# Inno Setup: Single installer that reads names from an INI file and creates an installation for each name

Tags: arrays, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am using a Pascal Script function to read and detect how many names are in an array in a file. When it has determined the amount of names, I want a `#for` loop to iterate for that amount.

I can read and detect the number of names with Pascal Script. The problem is, I don't know how to after the name counting process, set the `numberOfElements` variable's value. It has to be set to the number of names just read with the Pascal Script function.

Here is some example code:

```
#define numberOfElements

#sub CreateSubInstallation
[Languages]
//code ommitted

[Files]
//code ommitted

[Run]
//code ommitted

#endsub
#for {i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++} CreateSubInstallation
```

A different method of doing this would also be fine. I just want to read a number of names from a file and then make copies of the installation for the amount of names. Therefore each name has its' own installation. To elaborate even more, each name has it's own: directory,sub-directories and variables in files that will get the name "injected" into them.

Here is the format of the INI file:

```
[Customer]
customers={"customerName1","customerName2"}
```

Here is the code for reading and detecting the names with Pascal Script:

```pascal
{ Get the customer names from file }
function GetCustomersFromFile(fileName : string): string;
var
  lines: TArrayOfString;
  amountOfLines,i: integer;
  tempResult: string;
begin
  tempResult := '';
  if LoadStringsFromFile(fileName, lines) then
  begin
    amountOfLines := GetArrayLength(amountOfLines);
    { Keep reading lines until the end of the file is reached }
    for i := 0 to amountOfLines - 1 do
    begin
      if (Pos('customers', lines[i]) = 1) then
        tempResult := lines[i];
    end;

    { if not found return -1 }
    if (tempResult = '') then
      { this result is for debugging and }
      { will have no impact on the array population process }
      tempResult := '-1';

    Result := tempResult;
  end;
end;

{ Count the number of elements present in the array in the file }
{ Done for tempArray initilization }
function CountNumberOfStringElements(line : string): integer;
const 
  chars = ['0'..'9', 'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z'];
var
  ignoreCommas: Boolean;
  numElements, numValidText: integer;
  i: integer;
begin
  ignoreCommas := false;
  numValidText := 0;
  numElements := 0;
  { Loop through text }
  for i := 0 to Length(line) - 1 do
  begin
    if (line[i] = '"') then
      ignoreCommas := (NOT ignoreCommas);

    if ((line[i]) IN chars AND (ignoreCommas)) then
      Inc(numValidText);

    if((line[i] = ',') AND (NOT ignoreCommas) )then
      Inc(numElements);
  end;

  if (numElements >= 1) then
    result := numElements + 1
  else if ((numElements = 0) AND (numValidText > 0)) then
    result := 1
  else if ((numElements = 0) AND (numValidText = 0)) then
    result := 0;
end;
```

This is essentially what I want the installer to do, just a very stripped down version.

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
WizardStyle=modern
DefaultDirName={autopf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output
ArchitecturesAllowed=x64
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64

[Files]
Source: "MyProg-x64.exe"; DestDir: "{app}/customer1/"; DestName: "MyProg.exe"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}/customer1/"
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}/customer1/"; Flags: isreadme

Source: "MyProg-x64.exe"; DestDir: "{app}/customer2/"; DestName: "MyProg.exe"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}/customer2/"
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}/customer2/"; Flags: isreadme

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
```

**Please note** the reason why it is structured like this is because they are services. Each service eventually gets more populated with customer related content. The entire installation process has to be done with an .exe and the removal process with a different but also singular .exe.

Comment: That makes no sense. `#for` is a **preprocessor** directive. It is evaluated on **compile-time**. While **Pascal Script** runs on **run/install time**. So you cannot use `#for`/preprocessor to process an Pascal Script array. You have to use Pascal Script code. Or create the array in preprocessor. That depends whether your code needs to run on the compile or the install time. This is [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578). Ask about what you want to implement, rather than asking about your attempted solution.

Comment: I need to install Windows services. The services use the same installation files with different variable and file names. These file names are written in an .ini file in an array next to the Inno Setup .exe file. For every name in the array, an installation has to be executed and the services' name should contain one of the names specified in the array. After this the service has to be started. 

Literally all I want to do is read from the file, iterate through the names and make installations for each name.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am open to different implementations. Your help would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: You didn't explain the most important thing: Do you want the INI file to be distributed along your installer as a separate file? => Do you plan to keep the same installer and just change the INI file? Or do you need the INI file on the target machine? - Or do you want the INI file to be processed on a compile time? So that you have just one file to distribute. - Or do you need the INI file on the target machine, but do you want to embed it to the installer?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, I want the INI file to be distributed along with the installer - I plan to keep the same installer and just change the INI file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl , I updated the answer with the requested code and information about the INI file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thank you for the kind words. I was hoping you could point me in the right direction and maybe just indicate how this would be done what I am trying to do. I'm new to Inno Setup but I have to use it... so, any ideas?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I added a small example for you to view. The paragraph above the first "UPDATE" text has also been updated to provide more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your question is very unclear. But I'll try to give you some answer.*

If I understand correctly, you want to deploy the same set of files for each customer in your INI file. You cannot do that in Inno Setup using `[Files]` section, if you need to read the the INI file on run/install time (it is possible, if you read the INI file on compile time).

If you need to clone the files on run/install time, all you can do is to install them to a temporary folder and then copy them over using Pascal Script.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"

[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  I: Integer;
  SourcePath: string;
  TargetPath: string;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    for I := 0 to NumberOfCustomers - 1 then
    begin
      SourcePath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\MyProg.exe');
      TargetPath := GetPathForCustomer(I) + '\MyProg.exe';
      if FileCopy(SourcePath, TargetPath, False) then
      begin
        Log(Format('Installed for customer %d', [I]));
      end
        else
      begin
        Log(Format('Failed to install for customer %d', [I]));
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

*(You have to replace `NumberOfCustomers` and `GetPathForCustomer` with your implementation)*

Though this way, you won't get any progress bar and you lose all built-in error handling of Inno Setup. You will also have to implement uninstallation in Pascal Script.

---

It would definitely be better, if you read the INI file on a compile time. That means you will have to re-generate the installer with each change of the INI file. But that can be done with a command-line compiler by a single click.

Though parsing your INI file with a preprocessor won't be easy.

---

Another hackish solution is to generate a large number of identical entries in the `[Files]` section, which can then be dynamically associated with the customers on run/install time. It's not universal, as there will always be an upper limit. But if you know that you will never have a more than e.g. 100 customers, it is a viable option. And progress bar, error handling and uninstallation will work.

---

*I do not understand, what does `[Languages]` section have to do with the INI file, so I'm skipping that.*

---

*Side note: Your `GetCustomersFromFile` and `GetCustomersFromFile` can be replaced with few lines of code with use of [`GetIniString`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getinistring) and `TStringList.CommaText`. But that's for a separate question.*